# How do I automatically trigger a button click after 5 seconds with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an 'Accept' button which I would like to be automatically clicked after 5 seconds. I'm using React with Next.js.  The button code is:

```
<button name="accept" className="alertButtonPrimary" onClick={()=>acceptCall()}>Accept</button>
```

If I can't do this, I would like to understand why, so I can improve my React and Next.js skills.

Comment: Instead of automatically clicking the button, why not just automatically call the `acceptCall` function? Either way, you're probably looking for something with [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Or are you trying to run the handler function 5s after the button was clicked? If so look into debouce functions, there are many examples on the web.

Comment: I tired to automatically call the acceptCall function but it ends up re-rendering the page and calling the function infinitely.   I tried {acceptCall} {acceptCall()} {()=>acceptCall()}. Plus, I like the idea of the option to click the button but after 5 seconds it clicks anyway.

Comment: Assuming functional component, you'd need to put the timeout inside a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array so that it only runs one time. If in a class component, put it inside `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Is there an example or reference to a useEffect with an empty dependency array so that it only runs one time?  Thank you sincerely for the help!

Comment: Untested, but something like this: `React.useEffect(() => { setTimeout(acceptCall, 5000) }, []);`

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing you want this activated 5 seconds after render, in that case, put a setTimeout inside of the useEffect hook, like so. this will call whatever is in the hook after the render is complete.
Although this isn't technically activating the button click event.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     acceptCall()
  }, timeout);
}, [])
```

in that case you should use a ref like so,

```
const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const myfunc = () => {
    console.log("I was activated 5 seconds later");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      ref.current.click();
    }, 5000); //miliseconds
  }, []);

  return (
    <button ref={ref} onClick={myfunc}>
      TEST
    </button>
  );
};
```

Hopefully, this is what you are looking for.

https://codesandbox.io/s/use-ref-forked-bl7i0?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `ref` for the `<button>` and set a timeout inside of an effect hook to call the button click event after 5 seconds.

You could throw in a state hook to limit the prompt.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const buttonRef = useRef("accept-button");
  const [accepted, setAccepted] = useState(false);

  const acceptCall = (e) => {
    alert("Accepted");
  };

  const fireEvent = (el, eventName) => {
    const event = new Event(eventName, { bubbles: true });
    el.dispatchEvent(event);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!accepted) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (buttonRef.current instanceof Element) {
          setAccepted(true);
          fireEvent(buttonRef.current, "click");
        }
      }, 5000);
    }
  }, [accepted]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        name="accept"
        className="alertButtonPrimary"
        ref={buttonRef}
        onClick={acceptCall}
      >
        Accept
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Used setInterval instead of setTimeout to retry every 5 seconds.  Thanks everyone for the help!